# how to debug python modules while developing

Tags: python, python-module

Let's say we are developing a simple python module with the following directory structure

```
.
├── module
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── core.py
│   └── helpers.py
└── test.py
```

contents of **init**.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from .core import print_values
```

contents of core.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from .helpers import values

def print_values():
    print(values)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_values()
```

contents of helpers.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

values = [0, 2, 6]
```

contents of test.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from module import print_values
print_values()
```

now if we run `python test.py` with `'.'` as the working dir we get the expected output of `[0, 2, 6]`. Great!

So here is the problem, if we change the working dir to `'./modules'` and run `python3 ./core.py` the following error will be raised:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

So the question is how to design modules in a way that we can run python scripts from within it during development?

Answer (score 0):

so the problem appears to be that relative imports coupled with the `from` keyword tries to import a `__init__.py` file.

In other words, the line

```
from .helpers import values
```

tries to read ./modules/helpers/**init**.py, which does not exist. In order to make it work we change the import to:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    from helpers import values
else:
    from .helpers import values
```

Note: since there are a lot of links on google that explain this problem from other use cases (using setup.py as possible solutions for example), i thought it would be a good idea to publish this specific case as i did not encounter it while searching for an answer.